# BULK INSERT Operating System Error Code 32

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am making use of BULK INSERT within a stored procedure and I get this error:

```
Cannot bulk load because the file "D:vanAS_TEST_vanRunGroupervan_DB.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 32(error not found).
```

Notice the path has no slashes although it does when I use the BULK INSERT. In addition, I get a code 32 and although the error description was not found. When I looked it up in a few forums (nothing definitive) it seems that the error code relates to:

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Can anyone confirm this?

Also, why is the file path missing slashes when the bulk insert command was passed a file path with slashes?

Thanks all for any help

### Update

This is how I call the stored procedure:

```
exec data_Import ''D:\van\AS_TEST_van\Run\Grouper\van_DB.csv'', APCE_1011_Grouper_Out_FCE
```

This is how I run the bulk insert within the stored procedure:

```
exec('BULK INSERT dbo.' + @Table + ' FROM ''' + @PathFileName + ''' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR ='','', FIRSTROW = 2, ROWTERMINATOR =''\n'')')
```

*Please note, I have edited file paths.*

Comment: How are you "making use of BULK INSERT". What commands are you using?

Comment: I have updated my quesiton. This always works, on several servers its deployed on. For some reason, this has cropped upon one of the servers.

Comment: Yes, windows error 32 is ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION. In the platform SDK there's a very useful command line utility, err.exe, to look up error codes.

Comment: Thank you for confirming Rup. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason I got this error code is that at an unfortunate split second of time another program accessed this file and had a lock on it!

I hope this helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the "\" with double backslaches "\". Th way iread it the \ is ignored because it does not result in a control character with the following character. Backslash is a special character in SQL.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure that would work. Just to let you know, this has worked countless times. Its something external to the current code and procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure files you're trying to import are located on the server. Or modify path to read them from network share, ie. `\\PC1\\imports\....`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your target folder is not "read-only" checked in the property.